# Some networks time out when I trying to make AJAX calls to my server

Tags: node.js, ajax, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I have an application with a React/Redux frontend deployed on AWS S3, and an Express/Mongo backend deployed on AWS EC2. The application works fine on MOST networks.

However, on a certain network, whenever the frontend tries to make any AJAX call to the backend, I get a timeout error:

"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

So far, it's only this particular internet that is giving me the error, and it also happens to be a government site's network. I'm thinking there may be some setting I need to configure on my AWS EC2 server?

Comment: make sure that your adblocker is not on

Comment: @pudility that didn't work :(

Comment: Are you using a weird port?  i.e., not 80/443?

Comment: You need to use something like firebug or chrome dev tools to find out which calls are failing and take it from there. As well as that, this is a question would be better served on ServerFault.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i am using port 3090 and on AWS i have inbound security rules allowing any IP address. I did notice though that when you navigate to just the URL of the server, it shows the main splash page. However, when add :3090 to the url, it errors out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out. The network firewall was blocking the specific port (3090) of my server, but not the url of the server itself so I just forwarded port 80 to 3090 and now the network firewall doesn't block it.

Comment: That's why I asked about the port.  It's not unheard-of for a network to pass traffic over well-known ports only.  Note, also, [Let's Encrypt](http://letsencrypt.org) is a legitimate, trusted certificate authority that will give you an SSL certificate for free.  There is no catch, no shady characters behind the scenes -- it sounds too good to be true, but it isn't. I am not affiliated with that organizarion, but I mention it because there is really no longer any reason not to be using HTTPS (on port 443).    If you use ELB/ALB or CloudFront, Amazon Certificate Manager certs are free, too.